# Joomla still load CSS and Javascript from old domain when I change it

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, joomla2.5, base-url

I have a Joomla 2.5 project hosted on a domain mywebsite.com and all was working fine. But when I want to work on it in my local machine, Joomla keeps loading CSS and Javascript from mywebsite.com. 
I tried to clear the cache and make a global research on the project for something hard coded, but I haven't found the solution.
This how I include Javascript:

```
$document->addScript('media/system/js/jquery.min.js');
```

Could someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Which version of joomla?

Comment: i bet it's coded in your template's folder somewhere, probably in `index.php` in `/joomla_root/templates/templatename/index.php` if not in one of your main config files. Or just change template and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your config file and made sure your base path hasn't been hardcoded anywhere?

Comment: When I execute ` print_r( JURI::base()  );` it show me the localhost URL. I tried also to export the database and search for **mywebsite.com** I found it in the table `_redirect_links` then I truncate it and test again, but no chance.

Comment: Thinks to all of you. The problem was on CDN: my joomla installation was loading all from CDN. So I change this in database.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan suggested that you look in configuration.php and that was good advice.